# TableSorter Alpha before Number sort

Tags: sorting, tablesorter, numeric

I have seen and tried the options to have

```
textSorter: {
        // plain text sort
        3: $.tablesorter.sortText
        },
and setting the class of the column to class="sorter-text"
and setting the stringTo: "min",
```

Each time I add in one of the options above, I see the sort change, but in the end the values in the column do not sort the numbers correctly in the order within the alpha sort.  The alpha sort puts them in the correct order but not the numeric part.

The values are: 
Past Due by 3 Days
Past Due by 23 Days
Past Due by 0 days
Due In 1 day
Due in 2 day

As you can see the alpha is in the right descending order but the numeric part is only going by the first digit of the number (also descending) and not the number value so it is order of sequence.  So it should sort by alpha then sort by the numeric value within that alpha sort.   I cant be the first person to have this problem.  I have searched and found the many solutions shown above but they do not seem to solve this specific problem.  some would say to move the digits to the front of the string and then sort by digit only, but then all the past dues and due soons are mixed together and that is not the desired result.

I have seen some options to create my own custom parser, but I really can not believe in the year 2018 that tablesorter (I just started using it) still has this basic issue with sorting.

Comment: Did you try *not* setting the `textSorter` option? It uses a natural sort algorithm by default which should sort your data as expected - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/1819/).

Comment: yes I tried with each one indiv and then none at all and the results did not match as I would desire.

Comment: Please share your expected sorting result.

Comment: This is the desired sort order: Due In 1 day, Due in 2 day, Past Due by 0 days, Past Due by 3 Days, Past Due by 23 Days   I have decided to put the numeric info in its own column and the alpha in its own column as well and use the shift key on the two column headers to get the sort of the two at the same time.

Comment: Hmm, maybe include a [`data-value` attribute](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-defaultattrib) instead - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/1821/).